# lttng command not found when trying to run Linux Tracing Toolkit

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, trace, toolkit, lttng

I'd like to use the lttng Linux Tracing Toolkit for my machine running Ubuntu 14.04, but I'm running into the "lttng: command not found" terminal response when issue the lttng command.

Here is the script I ran to get lttng on my machine: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10816886/

I've also added tracing to my username to the tracing group.

Comment: Please install `lttng-tools` http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/lttng-tools → `/usr/bin/lttng` -

Answer (score 0):

The script you mentioned will install everything in /usr/local which is probably not in your system PATH.

I would suggest using one of our PPA to get up to date lttng packages at https://launchpad.net/~lttng